# Conditional MessageBoxes

Tags: c#

I'm currently making a script to display particular MessageBoxes if different conditions are fulfilled. **I have 8 conditions to check for and each of them have to display different MessageBoxes if they are "0" or "1".**

An shortened example of my code is as follows:

```
// Similar if(y[1] == "1") statements above with similar Messages but without the corresponding fruit(s)

if (y[2] == "1")
{ MessageBox.Show("Multiple goods required! Please get the following
                   items off the shelves" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "1. Apple" + Environment.NewLine + "2. Pear" +
                   Environment.NewLine + "3. Orange");
}

else if (y[2] == "0")
{ MessageBox.Show("Multiple goods required! Please get the following
                   items off the shelves" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "1. Apple" + Environment.NewLine + "2. Pear");
}
```

My knowledge of C# is quite basic, but I'm willing to learn! Please help!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make messages conditionally, and write the code for showing the message box once:

```
string msg = "Multiple goods required! Please get the following items off the shelves";

if(y[2] == "0" || y[2] == "1")
{
    msg += Environment.NewLine + "1. Apple"
            + Environment.NewLine + "2. Pear";

    if (y[2] == "1")
        msg += Environment.NewLine + "3. Orange";

    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

I just made the above to be equivalent to your code, otherwise I think it could be written much better.

Also consider using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) and [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) for creating the message, instead of concatenating small strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Didn't think of using strings to show in my messageboxes!

Answer (score 0):

if your question is how to display the messageboxes easier it would be this way :

```
for(int i =0;i<y.length;i++){
            if(y[i] == 0){
                MessageBox.Show("Multiple goods required! Please get the following
                   items off the shelves" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "1. Apple" + Environment.NewLine + "2. Pear");
            }
            else if(y[i] == 1){
                MessageBox.Show("Multiple goods required! Please get the following
                   items off the shelves" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "1. Apple" + Environment.NewLine + "2. Pear" +
                   Environment.NewLine + "3. Orange");
            }
        }
```

if this was not your question let me know i will come back and try to help